# MySQL has a table with 2 columns. How to generate list with only single column?

Tags: java, mysql, spring

MySQL database includes a table with two column. I am trying to generate a list to display data of one column only. I have tried @Query but it is throwing Casting error. Is there other possible alternative? Appreciate some guidance for this newbie here. Thank you!

When I remove the @Query, both columns are extracted from mySQL correctly, so there's no issue with the connection.

```
@Query("select p.date from PublicHoliday p" )
    List<PublicHoliday> findAll();
```

```
    List<PublicHoliday> phList = phRepo.findAll();
```

Error message from web:

```
Failed to convert from type [java.util.ArrayList<?>] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query java.util.List<sg.edu.nus.lms1.model.PublicHoliday>] for value '[2019-05-19, 2019-05-20, 2019-06-04, 2019-08-09]'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query sg.edu.nus.lms1.model.PublicHoliday]
```

Even if I change it to ArrayList in the codes:

```
Failed to convert from type [java.util.ArrayList<?>] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query java.util.ArrayList<sg.edu.nus.lms1.model.PublicHoliday>] for value '[2019-05-19, 2019-05-20, 2019-06-04, 2019-08-09]'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query sg.edu.nus.lms1.model.PublicHoliday]
```

Comment: You need a RowMapper to take in a java.sql.Date and return a PublicHoliday.  Why do you need JPA?  Start simple with JdbcTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

If you query for date sequence, why do you expect list of PublicHoliday's objects? Framework does not know how to convert dates into your model instances.

//edit

Simplest approach if you want to use Spring Data is to change query result collection to `List<Date>` like below:

```
@Query("select p.date from PublicHoliday p" )
List<Date> findAll();
```

With such construction, JPA will know how to convert your query result (date sequence) to proper collection of these dates.

I recommend to change that method's name, because it's default query name generated by Spring Data (look at: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.1.8.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods)

Comment: The first column is a Date type and second column is a String type.

Comment: Appreciate some guidance as to how to list from this type of table.. thank you in advance!